# Which libraries do I need to link against with MinGW for an object file built with Clang?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using an object file built with Clang. But no matter what library arguments I pass to `ld.exe`, it seems to always spit back unresolved references, stuff like `memcpy`, Standard library, stuff, and implementation stuff like _cxa_atexit.

What libraries (and in what order?) do I need to pass to the MinGW linker to get it to link my object file into an executable?

Edit:

I changed the triple from "i686-pc-mingw" to "i686-pc-mingw32" and it solved most of the problems- Clang does the old D3D9 trick of "Silently fail when the input is clearly wrong and there's no way the output could be correct". But I'm left with just two unresolved externals- it's some `std::_Hash_impl` for `float` and `double`, with no change. The program is just "Hello, World!". Curiously, neither clang++.exe nor g++.exe have a problem with compiling the source, but if I compile it using the Clang C++ API to .o, and then pass it back to MinGW, I get the unresolved externals.

Comment: Any specific reason why you're not letting clang do the link? (Or possibly g++, don't know if the object files are compatible.) Is that not available on Windows?

Comment: Because I need to use the Clang C++ API, so I would effectively have to do it myself.

Comment: (I didn't understand how that prevents you from using clang++ to link, but I've never done that.) Did you trying building a dummy C++ source with `clang++ -v foo.cpp` and using/adapting the linker call displayed?

Comment: I'm trying that right now, but convincing clang++ to accept the 4.6.3 mingw libstdc++ headers isn't so simple.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not a good idea to use different toolchains when building a binary. It is entirely possible that the different tools' ideas of names of symbols won't match up.

Still, trying to answer your actual quesiton:

`-lstdc` would be a minimum requirement and `-lstdc++` if it's C++ code. without knowing what your code does, it's impossible to say if you need more of them.

Comment: g++ -lstdc++ foo.obj, and similar for ld, but still a ton of unresolved externals.

Comment: You probably want to add the library last, since the linker will only look for "so far unresolved" entries.

Comment: Changing the argument order had no effect. Also, just in reference to your main answer, Clang is explicitly intended to be compatible with MinGW on Windows.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I will have to refer to the first paragraph in my answer - don't mix tools.

Comment: It is impossible to not mix tools with Clang on Windows- that's the only way it ever worked and is supposed to work, until libc++ works on Windows.